# Elasticsearch in python not working?

Tags: python-2.7, elasticsearch

I am starting a project where I need to use Elasticsearch in python (I am using 2.7.12) on my MacBook Air, when trying to enter pip install elasticsearch python comes up with a syntax error, any help would be appreciated.
Kind regards,

Comment: Please include code which is [MCVE], as well as the syntax error your are receiving, otherwise there is no way anyone can read your mind, as much as we'd all wish too.

Comment: I am trying to write the code pip install elasticsearch                to which python highlights install, I have tried easy_install, but this also doesn't work